# Can't map over state after I dispatch an action from a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I created a simple react app that uses redux to manage the state but when I dispatch the action to delet a specific state it fails to map over the new state and I get this error
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')*

**here are my app components:**

**ACTIONS**

```
import { DELETE_ARTICLE, ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/action-types";

let lastID = 3


export function addArticle(msg) {
  return {
    type: ADD_ARTICLE, 
    payload:{
      message:msg,
      id: ++lastID
    }
  }
};

export function deleteArticle(id) {
  return {
    type: DELETE_ARTICLE,
    payload:{
      id:id
    }
  }
};
```

**REDUCER**

```
import { ADD_ARTICLE, DELETE_ARTICLE } from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = {
  articles: [{id:1, title:'hello'}, {id:2, title:'hi'}, {id:3, title:'bye'}]
};

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === ADD_ARTICLE) {
    return [
      ...state.articles,
      {id: action.payload.id, title:action.payload.message}
      ];
  } else if (action.type === DELETE_ARTICLE) {
    return state.articles.filter(task => task.id !== action.payload.id)
  }
  return state;
}

export default rootReducer
```

**REACT COMPONENT**

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import { deleteArticle } from "../actions/index";



function List(){
  const articles = useSelector((state) => state.articles);
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return(
    <>
      <ul>
        {articles.map(
          el => (<li key={el.id}>{el.title} <button onClick={()=>dispatch(deleteArticle(el.id))}>Delete</button></li>)
        )}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
export default List;
```

So, After I start the App is looks normal and all state are rendered but once I click on the delete button I Get this error:

```
List.jsx:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
        at List (List.jsx:13:1)
        at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
        at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17356:1)
        at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19063:1)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
        at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
        at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
        at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)

The above error occurred in the <List> component:
    
        at List (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:258:76)
        at div
        at App
        at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35403:20)
    
    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
    Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
        at List (List.jsx:13:1)
        at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
        at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17356:1)
        at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19063:1)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
        at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
        at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
        at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line in your reducer, in response to the `DELETE_ARTICLE` action:

```
else if (action.type === DELETE_ARTICLE) {
  return state.articles.filter(task => task.id !== action.payload.id)
}
```

This replaces your entire state - an object containing several properties including the articles array under `articles` - with just that (now filtered) array. This causes an issue because `state.articles` is now undefined.

You need to return your state unchanged, as an object, with just the `articles` array updated:

```
return { ...state, articles: state.articles.filter(task => task.id !== action.payload.id) };
```